# Can't stub Curl method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stub

Here's my test:

```
# Custom validation method tests
  describe "#ticker_symbol" do
    before(:each) do
      o = OpenStruct.new(:body => '')
      Curl::Easy.any_instance.stub(:get).and_return(o)
    end
    it "should add an error" do
      subject
    end
  end
```

And the relevant part of my model:

```
# Custom validation methods
  def ticker_symbol
    apiresponse = Curl.get("https://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=" + ticker)
    debugger
    if apiresponse.body == ''
      errors.add(:ticker, "must be valid")
    end
  end
```

For some reason, apiresponse isn't what it should be:

```
apiresponse
#<Curl::Easy https://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoq>
```

Any idea why my stubbing isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Custom validation method tests
describe "#ticker_symbol" do
  let(:stubbed_response) { OpenStruct.new(:body => '') }
  before(:each) do
    Curl.stub(:get).and_return stubbed_response
  end
  it "should add an error" do
    subject
  end
end
```